# Error calling async method non asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I have the following async method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/SecurityRoles/AllowDeleteRole/{securityRoleId}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AllowDeleteRole(int securityRoleId)
{
    _systemLogger.LogInfo($"Method api/SecurityRoles/AllowDeleteRole (Get) called with securityRoleId: {securityRoleId}");

    var securityRolePermission =
            await _securityRolePermissionService.SecurityRolePermissionsCountBySecurityRoleId(securityRoleId);
    if (securityRolePermission != SecurityRoleDeleteResult.Success) return Ok(SecurityRoleDeleteResult.RolePermissionExists);

    var securityRolePageEntity =
            await  _securityRolePageEntityService.SecurityRolePageEntityCountBySecurityRoleId(securityRoleId);
    return Ok(securityRolePageEntity != SecurityRoleDeleteResult.Success ? SecurityRoleDeleteResult.RolePageEntityExists : SecurityRoleDeleteResult.Success);
    }
```

It gets used in numerous places, but for this one instance I need to use it non-async, so I have the following code that first wraps it:

```
public async Task<SecurityRoleDeleteResult> AllowDeleteRole(int securityRoleId)
    {
        string url = $"{_housingDataSecurityConfiguration.HousingDataSecurityWebApiUrl}SecurityRoles/AllowDeleteRole/{securityRoleId}";
        var message =  _apiClientService.Retrieve<HttpResponseMessage>(url);

        if (message.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        {
            return SecurityRoleDeleteResult.ErrorOccurred;
        }

        int intResult = 0;
        var apiResult = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if (int.TryParse(apiResult, out intResult))
        {
            return (SecurityRoleDeleteResult)intResult;
        }
        else
        {
            return SecurityRoleDeleteResult.ErrorOccurred;
        }
    }
```

before getting called with:

```
public  SecurityRoleViewModel BuildViewModelForEdit(int id)
{

    var enableButton = false;
    _securityRoleService.AllowDeleteRole(id).ContinueWith(result =>
        {
            enableButton = (result.Result == SecurityRoleDeleteResult.Success) ? true : false;

    });

    SecurityRoleViewModel model = new SecurityRoleViewModel()
    {
        SecurityRole = _securityRoleService.SecurityRoleRetrieve(id),
        RolePermissions = _securityRoleService.SecurityRolePermissionsRetrieve(id),
        EnableDeleteButton = enableButton 
    };
    return model;
}
```

My issue is that when I try to set `EnableDeleteButton = enableButton` in the model, it throws the following error back up on the line:

```
enableButton = (result.Result == SecurityRoleDeleteResult.Success) ? true : false;
```

> {"Error converting value 3 to type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage'. Path '', line 1, position 1."}

3 refers to one of my enum values on my SecurityRoleDeleteResult enums.

Comment: When you see an error message like this you should carefully analyse the objects you're using. It's rarely wrong, and by "rarely wrong" I mean it's telling you all the information you need: one type is represented by 3 (the enum) and the other is an HttpResponseMessage (the result). I don't know why you would expect anything else when you've written `return Ok(...)` in the first method.

Comment: `"Use implicit typing for local variables when the type of the variable is obvious from the right side of the assignment, or when the precise type is not important"`... This suggestion taken from [Coding Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions) might save you some time if you'd followed it here.

Comment: You're comparing an `enum` with an `IHttpActionResult`. Besides, remember that `IHttpActionResult` was designed to be used asynchronously so this might not be what you intended.

Comment: Sorry all, I've added a Wrapper method and placed this above for clarity. I still receive the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AllowDeleteRole` returns a `HttpResponseMessage`. The `result`object you pass into your Lambda is of Type `Task<IHttpActionResult>`. So when you do `result.Result` the object you are now working with an `IHttpActionResult` more specifically it is a `HttpResponseMessage` it appears.

This is the cause of your problem

Comment: Hi @Dave, I've added another wrapper method to my question to make my issue clearer (should have done that originally), So the  issue is that `BuildViewModel` for edit gets called first, this then calls the asyc Task method which wraps the call to the API. The `continueWIth` is returning before the wrapper strips the content, thus the invalid return type.

Comment: @bilpor The wrapper method you mention, you call it a wrapper but from looking at it it never calls the original method. Without seeing all your class structure I can't give too much guidance but the error message is not wrong. The Task you are working with in your country continuation has a Result property of type of `IHttpActionResult`. That is a fact. So from what you've told me it appears you are calling the wrong method

Comment: It also doesn't help that your 'wrapper' method (which doesn't appear to wrap anything?) Is named exactly them same and has the same parameters as the 'original' method just with a different return type, this just makes debugging difficult

Comment: Just for clarity..I needed to change the return type from `IHttpActionResult` to `SecurityRoleDeleteResult`